# Is there to list of all inputs and outputs declared in Shiny app

Tags: r

Hope you are having good weekend.

I wanted to check with you all that is there a way to check all inputs and outputs declared in Shiny app. For example for the below ui.R there are 2 inputs and 1 outputs

ui.R

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       numericInput("n", "Number to add", 5),
                   actionButton("add", "Add")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("sum", placeholder = TRUE)
    )
  )))
```

Expected output

```
Inputs 
>"n", "add"

outputs
>"sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `names` since we can consider `input/output` as a `list`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$sum <- renderText({
    paste(names(input), collapse = ",")
  })
})
```